# How to convert Java POJO to JSON model and example through Swagger like it shows in swagger-ui

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I'd like to know if there is a simple way to re-use some utility in *any* of the swagger projects such that I can achieve something similar to this:

```
String model = SomeSwggerUtil.generateModelString(MyPojo.class);
String example = SomeSwggerUtil.generateExampleString(MyPojo.class);
```

I am looking to generate the same *model* and *example* string that Swagger-UI shows on its Swagger-UI web page.

What class/utility do I call to accomplish that?

Comment: Could you please clarify what your actual goal is? Do you need to generate a Swagger definition from your code? How are you going to use the examples? The answers to your question might be different depending on your use case.

Comment: I going to use them the same way swagger-ui uses them: provide the user the ability to see the model and copy it so they can paste it elsewhere to issue a request. I need to do this dynamically because I am writing a library/framework and don't know upfront what these POJOs are, and have no control over them.

Answer (score -1):

When I want to create modules from my swagger definitions, I use the [swagger-codegen tool](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#generating-libraries-from-your-server). It generates modules in different langs, and there is some Java support. There is an `-i` flag that lets you point to your swagger definition file. After getting the CLI codegen tool install, the command would look something like:

```
swagger-codegen-cli generate -i "/path/to/swaggerDefinition"
```

Comment: Not it. I need to generate these models dynamically.